# Python: How to obtain an instance's name at runtime?

Tags: python, runtime, pyqt, stylesheet, instance

I'm using PyQt. And because I'm using Qt Style Sheets, I have to set object names to widgets which I want to specify in my style rules (e.g "#deleteButton { font-size: 14px; }").
In code, I have to do:

```
...
self.deleteButton = QToolButton(self)
self.deleteButton.setObjectName("deleteButton")
...
```

But I would to do:

```
...
self.deleteButton = QToolButton(self)
self.deleteButton.setObjectName(self.deleteButton.__give_my_instance_name__)
...
```

If I find a way, I can apply it to all widgets in the container.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't give it a name then it doesn't *have* one...

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744792/accessing-the-name-that-an-object-being-created-is-assigned-to , but not a duplicate, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to accomplish is better done with this code:

```
for name, obj in self.__dict__.iteritems():
    if isinstance(obj, QtCore.QObject) and not obj.objectName(): # QObject without a name
        obj.setObjectName(name)
```

Use it at the end of your object creation routine.

Comment: I was realizing that I have to play with **__dict__** too. But you gave me the coded solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

[How to obtain an instance's name at runtime?](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/1999-June/615927.html)

Comment: Thanks, I read the discussion and I learned something more about Python, but I didn't found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

A general answer (with example). Let's say we have a class `Foo`, and we want it to describe what it is called:

```
class Foo(object):
    def my_name_is(self):
        for name, obj in globals().items():
            if obj is self:
                print('My name is ' + repr(name))

bar = Foo()
bar.my_name_is()
# prints: My name is 'bar'
```

This works perfectly is you have only one copy of that object. However, if you copy it, then it can have multiple names:

```
other_bar = bar
other_bar.my_name_is()
# prints two lines: My name is 'other_bar'
#                   My name is 'bar'
```