# Python object hierarchy; Referencing an owner instance?

Tags: python, oop, class, object, relationship

Is there no magic python way of accessing the instance of the class that has a reference to the current self inside it?
ie:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.B = B()

    def say_hi(self):
        print "Hi"

class B(object)
    def __init__(self):
        __get_owner_ref__.say_hi()

A()
```

**get_owner_ref** being the magic bullet that does not exist.
Is there a feature in python for this behaviour?

Yes I know I could pass a reference in to the constructor, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: If you're looking for mixins, that's not how you do it in python.

Comment: this thread might be interesting then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115844/recommended-python-publish-subscribe-dispatch-module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the second thought, what you're looking for pretty closely resembles [descriptors](http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm). Consider:

```
class Agent(object):
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        print 'Agent %s called from %s ' % (id(self), obj.name)

class X(object):
    agent = Agent()

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

a = X('Foo')
a.agent

b = X('Bar')
b.agent
```

Here the `agent` is attached to two different instances and "knows" each time which instance wants to talk to him.

Answer (score 4):

No, You'd have to do something like this

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.B = B(parent=self)

    def say_hi(self):
        print "Hi"

class B(object)
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent   # you don't need to do this, but it might be a good idea
        parent.say_hi()

A()
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no nice way of doing this. Pass a reference in to the initializer.

<sub>To preclude questions, it's probably possible in most cases to find the owner heuristically by inspecting the stack, something like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744792/accessing-the-name-that-an-object-being-created-is-assigned-to). But it will be fragile, buggy and difficult to understand. *And* it goes against the "explicit > implicit" philosophy.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know such a feature does not exist. Also, passing it in as reference to the constructor and calling `self.parent.say_hi()` is much more explicit and (indeed) elegant. And explicit is better than implicit or using magic language features.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you can use [`sys._getframe`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys._getframe):

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        import sys
        a = sys._getframe(1).f_locals['self']
        a.say_hi()
```

**But you should not do that**. It's bound to lead to confusion, will break on new Python implementations, will complicate debugging, and is prone to break.
There's a reason why `sys._getframe` is listed in [5 Years of Bad Ideas](https://ep2012.europython.eu/conference/talks/5-years-of-bad-ideas).

Instead, pass a reference, either to the parent object, or to the `say_hi` method.